# Openvpn doesn't log user disconnect event

Tags: openvpn

I am running CentOs 6.5 and OpenVPN server 2.3.6.
The task is to log info about VPN sessions: who logged in, when, from what ip, when disconnected. 
I have already done some part of the task. But how can i know when client VPN session was closed? I can't find any information about that in OpenVPN logs.

Also i want to know what resources user accessed during the session. I guess that i should use some kind of sniffer for that, but maybe there is another way to find it out?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that management is enabled in your server's config file. If not, add the directive:

```
management 127.0.0.1 5000
```

Here, you can access all information available from a running OpenVPN server. Connect with:

```
telnet localhost 5000
```

In order to extract and log custom data, I suggest using [this](https://github.com/ryankaiser/Net-OpenVPN-Manage) perl module. [Here is a simple example script](https://github.com/ryankaiser/Net-OpenVPN-Manage/blob/master/eg/vpnclients.pl), which extracts data about connected clients.

I think the "Last Ref" section reported with the "status" command will provide the raw information you need to log disconnection times. However, since this data is only available while the client is connected, its going to take some hacking to make the data accurate and persistent.